# Sql - update table using LIKE and Where clause

Tags: php, sql

Iam trying to update a table using where clause, but the query updates all the rows to the same result (image) in the image column:

```
<form action="" method="POST">                                  
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $items['firstname']?>"/><br>
</form>

$image =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name']));
$sql ="update employee set image='$image' where firstname LIKE '%".$_POST['fname']."%'";
```

Below is the code from my index file

````
  if(isset($_POST['search']))
                                    {
                                        $filtervalues = $_POST['search'];
                                        $query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE CONCAT(firstname,lastname) LIKE '%$filtervalues%' ";
                                        $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                                        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
                                        {
                                            foreach($query_run as $items)
                                            {
                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <form action="saveimage.php" method="POST">
                                            
                                                    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $items['firstname']?>"/><br>
                                                    </form>                                                  
                                                
                                                    <td><img class="zoom" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php  echo base64_encode($items['bilder']);?>" /></td>                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="4">No Record Found</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
      ```
````

Comment: Side note: this code will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Did you debug an see what the value of `$sql` is after these statements? It all comes down to that, irrespective of what comes before.

Comment: When I try: 'where firstname= 'firstname' ' (just for testing)an exiting user then it works fine. The proble is when I try to put the input value: 'firstname LIKE '%".$_POST['fname']."%'";'

Comment: Opps. sorry i missed the UPDATE query.     I am not sure about the above comments but your question says UPDATE, your query is  ""SELECT * FROM employee". You should be using something like; UPDATE xyz WHERE a LIKE b.   Or  UPDATE xyz SET col ="value" WHERE "something" LIKE "your value"  see this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp